# Выдвижная шторка сверху вниз. Android

Tags: android

Необходимо сделать выдвижную шторку, т.е. есть Layout, сверху кнопка, при клике выдвигается вниз другой Layout. Похоже на SlidingPaneLayout из support v4. Но только нажимать и(или) тянуть вниз.

Какие есть варианты реализовать такое? Готовые библиотеки не желательно. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, здесь есть то, что Вам нужно:
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/animation/overridependingtransition.php#overridependingtransition

Или посмотрите на ViewFlipper. Думаю, это можно применить к разным layout. Ведь они унаследованы от View. Тут есть пример: http://www.androhub.com/android-viewflipper/

А здесь ответ, как добавить layout программно: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759290/how-to-programmatically-add-view-in-viewflipper

Comment: Стартовать активити не нужно

Comment: в идеале классно подошёл SlidingDrawer, но устарел (